# Cordova based project to Fabric

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, fabric.io

I am searching for "**Crash Analytics and Monitoring tools**" for my Cordova (Ionic) based project.
There is a cordova-fabric-io-plugin on Github

*https://github.com/engincancan/cordova-fabric-io-plugin*.

I did changes according to instructions and also i installed intellij  plugin to my IDE **"intellij idea"**.Now when i click on fabric icon to upload it asks for Android Project as shows in below image link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVtL4.png

**How to upload a Cordova (Ionic) based project to Fabric?**

Comment: Did you ever figured that out ?

Comment: Well, you have to open xCode or Intellij Idea to manually push the project to Fabric!

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Android Studio or IntelliJ.

2) Ensure to install the Fabric plugin for Android Studio or IntelliJ.

3) Import the Android project present inside platforms/android folder of your cordova project.

4) Once imported Fabric should recognize the project and add the fabric SDK.